# Reversing a string and replace every other character with "-"

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I need to reverse a word in my text box to display in a label and then have every other character in the string be replaced by a "-". for example: input is `textbox1.text = worms`. I need the output to be `label1.text = s-r-w` (which is "worms" reversed: "smrow" with the "o" and the "m" replaced with "-")

This is what I have so far

```
    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

    'Displays equipment in label in reverse order
    label1.Text = reverse(textbox1.Text)

    Function reverse(ByVal info As String) As String
    Dim intM As Integer, strTemp As String = ""
    intM = info.Length
    For intJ As Integer = intM - 1 To 0 Step -1
        strTemp &= info.Substring(intJ, 1)
    Next
    Return strTemp
End Function
```

I got the reverse part but I cant figure out where to start to replace every other character with "-". Sorry I didn't post this the first time. I am new to SO!

Thanks guys

Comment: You've got to try something yourself and ask for help in specific areas you're having problems with.  That's how SO works.

Comment: As Jay said, try it out first before posting. This kind of smells like a homework question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Reverse` and `String.Replace`:

```
Dim reversed = textBox1.text.Reverse()
label1.Text = New String(reversed.ToArray()).Replace("o", "-").Replace("m", "-")
```

or this little query which includes both:

```
Dim newChars = From c In textBox1.Text.Reverse()
               Select If({"o", "m"}.Contains(c), "-"c, c)
label1.Text = New String(newChars.ToArray())
```

or probably even better since it also handles surrogates using the "forgotten" VisualBasic [`StrReverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e462ax87%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
label1.Text = Strings.StrReverse(textBox1.Text).Replace("o", "-").Replace("m", "-")
```

[Reversing a String that Contains Unicode Characters Expressed as Surrogate Pairs](http://csharp.2000things.com/2013/02/05/773-reversing-a-string-that-contains-unicode-characters-expressed-as-surrogate-pairs/)

**Update** if you need to replace every **second** character instead.

```
Dim newChars = textBox1.Text.Reverse().
    Select(Function(c, Index) If(Index Mod 2 = 0, c, "-"c) )
Label1.Text = New String(newChars.ToArray())
```

**Finally** here's an approach using a `StringBuilder` which replaces every nth character with another character if it's not an "ignore-character" (space in this case):

```
Public Shared Function ReplaceEveryNthChar(input As String, nth As Int32, newChar As Char, Optional ignoreChars As Char() = Nothing) As String
    If input Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("input")
    End If
    If input.Length = 0 Then Return ""
    If input.Length = 1 Then Return input ' don't replace the first as desired

    Dim ignore = New HashSet(Of Char)(If(ignoreChars, Enumerable.Empty(Of Char)()))
    Dim sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder(input.Length)
    Dim ignoredChars = 0 
    sb.Append(input(0)) ' don't replace the first as desired
    For pos As Int32 = 2 To input.Length
        Dim c = input(pos - 1) ' index zero based 
        If ignore.Contains(c) Then
            ignoredChars += 1
            sb.Append(c)
        ElseIf (pos - ignoredChars) Mod nth = 0 Then
            sb.Append(newChar)
        Else
            sb.Append(c)
        End If
    Next
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

You use it in this way:

```
Dim chars = textBox1.Text.ToCharArray()
Array.Reverse(chars)
label1.Text = ReplaceEveryNthChar(New String(chars), 2, "-"c, {" "})
```

Comment: This would work but I need to replace every other character for anything the user inputs into textbox1. If the user enters speed boat I need it to be displayed as t-o- d-e-s.

Comment: @pforde: what do you need to replace? It's not clear which character should remain and which should be replaced. What is the rule? Do you want to replave every second character?

Comment: I need to replace every other character in the string with "-". So if the input into textbox1.text is "patrick", I need the output in the label to be "k-i-t-p". If the input is "schmelter" the output would be "r-t-e-h-s". If it is multiple words such as "speed boat", the output would be "t-o- -e-p-". Does that make more sense? I feel like this requires the use of substring but I am not sure how to execute it.

Comment: So you need to replace every **second** character in a reversed string with -, is that correct?

Comment: I've edited my answer again with a better approach that also ignores spaces(as it seems that you don't want to replace white-spaces). Sorry for the misunderstanding, i didn't know that "every other" means "every second" since english is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

An old school solution, using a string builder and reverse loop:

```
Private Function MagicReplace(str As String) As String
  Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
  For i = str.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
      sb.Append(str.Chars(i))
    Else
      sb.Append("-")
    End If
  Next
  Return sb.ToString
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim output As String = MagicReplace("worms")
Console.WriteLine(output) 'outputs s-r-w
```